# Sphinx (searchd) not able to find newly indexed documents

Tags: php, sphinx

I am having a an issue with sphinx that I am having a hard time troubleshooting.  I am running a sphinx index job once a day.  The output of this job is

```
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6): /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /home/app/code/server_config/sphinx_config.php --rotate jt_lqo_index
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6): Sphinx 2.0.5-release (r3308)
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6): Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6): Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6):
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6): using config file '/home/app/code/server_config/sphinx_config.php'...
2018-08-09T13:41:12-07:00 INFO (6): indexing index 'jt_lqo_index'...
2018-08-09T14:12:15-07:00 INFO (6): collected 7425589 docs, 1111.2 MB
2018-08-09T14:16:58-07:00 INFO (6): sorted 983.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
2018-08-09T14:16:59-07:00 INFO (6): WARNING: 324357 duplicate document id pairs found
2018-08-09T14:16:59-07:00 INFO (6): total 7425589 docs, 1111230505 bytes
2018-08-09T14:16:59-07:00 INFO (6): total 2147.196 sec, 517526 bytes/sec, 3458.27 docs/sec
2018-08-09T14:16:59-07:00 INFO (6): total 95 reads, 2.116 sec, 72207.6 kb/call avg, 22.2 msec/call avg
2018-08-09T14:16:59-07:00 INFO (6): total 11651 writes, 16.540 sec, 1085.5 kb/call avg, 1.4 msec/call avg
2018-08-09T14:16:59-07:00 INFO (6): rotating indices: succesfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=10183).
```

It looks  to me like the documents that it found are being added and the index is rotating correctly.  However searches against any new data in the last two days return empty.  Searches against older data return fine.

This process has been running fine for years, until we had a system crash a couple days ago.  I have since restarted sphinx and indexed numerous times without any luck

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The only thing I can think of is, are you sure you are giving sphinx the updated data.  It wouldn't hurt to check what data you are feeding it.

Comment: I ran the raw query before this last run and it did return 7.4 million rows like it is saying above.  I am not sure what the impact of the duplicate message is and why the total writes is significantly less that the number of documents

Comment: Yea, I don't know either.  Sphinx generally just works, which is why l love it.  I would also check the process list and make sure only one copy of it is running, before I had some kind of Zombie process, but I cant remember it that was Sphinx or something else like RabbitMq.

Comment: Another thought, is stop sphinx, rename the data folder ( where it puts all the files and stuff) create an empty folder to replace it and then rebuild them from scratch.  Maybe they got corrupted somehow.  It should rebuild everything when it indexs, so its just grasping at straws.  But if you rename it, it shouldn't hurt anything, because you can allways name it back.

Comment: Other then that I love sphinx, we have a much smaller data set, but we run 2 copies on separate servers, and use rabbit to search it in parallel.  We do up to 180k searches a minute with it.  It's fantastic.

Comment: That is a good idea.  The dataset would be huge but that at least would give me some better answers to the problem

Comment: we are planning a migration to elasticsearch at some point next year.

Comment: I never used that, for sphinx we have about 200k rows of data, and it's split in 4 distributed index (on the same server) and then we run an additional server with the same copy.  Every night our DB outputs an XML file that both servers track the modified time of, and when it changes they reindex the sphinx, this way they both read from the same source and we have a hard copy of that source if we need to debug the data.  It works well, on top of that we have Rabbit that takes in CSV files, splits them into 1000 row chunks and searches with up to 12 workers and then recombines the results.

Comment: Sounds like searchd is not actully pid 10183. It can get confused in case of crashes. Stop `searchd` normally. Wait, Check no lingering searchd processes, if so `kill` them. check the `PID file` is gone, if not delete it. Start `searchd` up again.

Comment: thanks for all your help.  I ended up making a new index in a new directory but that did not fix anything.  The problem ended up being that sphinx was reading it's data from our 3rd read slave which had a replication error.